# What should be the name of our chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

I believe this question is asked on every private Beta... what should be the name of our chatroom?

Comment: ahem.. [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34216/3d-printing)...

Comment: Everyone that visits this post needs to come to the chat room. Really. People need to chat more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The Hotbed.**

Colloquially, "hotbed" generally refers to a center of activity. Here, it will have a double meaning (referencing the hot bed of a 3D printer.

Answer (score 2):

### sliced text

Slicing a 3d model is a necessary step for almost all 3D printing techniques, so that it can be printed layer by layer that eventually make up the 3D object.

In chat, people write text line by line which will eventually make up an entire conversation.

Answer (score 1):

#### The Box

Since everything happens in the box.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Things

Not to confused with Thingiverse.

Answer (score 0):

#### 4D!

Since printers are printing in 3D for now, it's better to think in advance:)

Answer (score -1):

## Filibusters!

I've heard that from somewhere. It's a play on the word "filament"

<sup>Oh, Just as a heads up, I can think of the weirdest names...</sup>

Comment: This will also give us a national anthem! "If there's something strange / in your 3d print / and it don't look good / Where you gonna go? FILIBUSTERS!" :-D