# Do we have a chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

Other Stack Exchange sites have a chatroom where people can ask simple queries, exchange technical ideas, raise concerns about SE posts, clarify points (where comments are not sufficient), or just for an informal chat.

Do we have such a chat room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact there are two public chatrooms:

- One, [The Hotbed - 3D Printing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34216/the-hotbed-3d-printing) chatroom, which was created here: [What should be the name of our chatroom?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-should-be-the-name-of-our-chatroom). This has a number of achieved chats, and was active up until the start of 2018
- Two, [Public 3D printing room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79830/public-3d-printing-room), which was created in June and which is currently our most active.